# Triggering reveal for a single element with a shared class

Tags: jquery

I have a number of divs with a shared class called 'reveal'.

Upon an element with that class scrolling into view, I would like to reveal that single element alone.

Currently my problem is that as soon as the first element with that class scrolls into view then all of the elements with that shared class are revealed as per code below:

```
var a = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var oTop = $('.reveal').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
        $('.reveal').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(2000);
        $('.reveal').addClass('animate');
        a = 1;
    }
});
```

I understand why this is happening as I am fading in anything with a class of reveal rather then the specific element that has just scrolled into view.

So how do I isolate only the element that has currently scrolled into view?

I've tried some of the below but with no joy

- Foreach loop
- $('reveal', this)
- .closest().find()

Please see jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/g6cqL539/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.reveal').each` will allow to to work with each reveal separately.

Instead of that random `a` variable I am removing the reveal class to mark that the element has already been revealed.
There are other ways you could keep track of that of course.  Up to you.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
    $('.reveal').each(function() {
        var reveal = $(this);
        var oTop = reveal.offset().top - window.innerHeight;
        if (windowScrollTop > oTop) {
            reveal.css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(2000);
            reveal.addClass('animate')
                .removeClass('reveal');
        }
    });
});
```

You probably also want to debounce your scroll function so it's not running constantly.  You could google how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Just looking into 'debounce' now.